# How to connect to a MQTT Broker with Websockets?

Tags: javascript, websocket, mqtt

I have a `test.html` file that I open with Chrome:

```
<html>   
<head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/mqtt/dist/mqtt.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        var client = mqtt.connect('ws://broker.hivemq.com:8000')
        client.subscribe("mqtt/demo")

        client.on("message", function (topic, payload) {
            alert([topic, payload].join(": "))
            client.end()
        })

        client.publish("mqtt/demo", "hello world!")
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately I have this error:

> mqtt.min.js:1 WebSocket connection to 'ws://broker.hivemq.com:8000/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

I also tried with `mqtt://` and it does not work. Any idea?

Comment: `mqtt://` will never work from within the browser as that will try and use native MQTT not MQTT over websockets.

Comment: What should I use ? wss ?

Comment: @hardillb if you look at https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js they use `mqtt://`

Comment: Yes, because they are not running that code in the browers, it's NodeJS code that is making native MQTT connection. You CAN NOT use `mqtt://` from inside the browser, you can only use `ws://` or `wss://`

Comment: I suggest you look at using the Paho JavaScript library instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This server has been stopped or down and cannot be accessed. Please use

```
ws://broker.emqx.io:8083/mqtt
```

or

```
ws://broker.mqttdashboard.com:8000/mqtt
```

to try